# Deploy update on jelastic cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devops, jelastic

I am currently building a web app using rails and react and deployed on Jelastic.
I made some changes since the last deployment, and I would like to deploy them.

So I clicked on the Update from git.

[image]

Then I ran "Bundle install" an "rails db:migrate". The migrations were applied, but when i went back to the appsite. The site was not updated. So I tried to restart the application node, but it did not work either.

[image]

I think I may need to restart the rails server, but I do not know how...

Comment: Does the [vcs_update.log](https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform-docs/view-log-files/) indicate that the git pull was successful + have you verified that the expected file changes occurred?

Comment: Yes the update did work cause when I ran db:migrate, the pending migration were applied. Except doing db:migrate and bundle install, do I have to run another command?

I have tried to run rails restart as well but nothing happened...